# Should this XPath expression work? //test/ancestor::test

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to find all `tbody` elements that contain a descendant `<font color="red">` element.

I'm using this XPath expression:

```
//font[@color="red"]/ancestor::tbody
```

but it doesn't work. Should it work or is this a problem with the library that I'm using (or elsewhere)? I'm using a Ruby library called [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

I also tried

```
//tbody[descendant::font[@color="red"]]
```

but still no luck.

Comment: The second expression should start with `//`. The first one should work. Are there any namespaces in your document?

Comment: Oops, I actually just forgot to put the two slashes `//` before the second expression (now fixed). So still, it doesn't work. Nope, there are no namespaces in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: there actually were no `tbody` elements in the source code of the document I was using!

I thought there were because I was browsing the source code using the Elements tab in Chrome's Developer Tools and this tool added `<tbody>` elements in there for some reason!

So the XPath expression below *should* work, and *does* work if the proper `tbody` elements actually exist in the source code.

```
//font[@color="red"]/ancestor::tbody
```

Comment: When you look there in Chrome you see Chrome's 'corrected' markup: eg if the html says `<table><tr><td>cell</td></tr></table>`, Chrome will supply the missing `tbody` element

Comment: This is why we always ask people to show a sample of the XML source.

Comment: @MichaelKay I probably would've copied the source sample using the Chrome Developer Tool, not knowing the tool can modify the source by itself :)

Comment: The proper way to diagnose this sort of issue is to download the HTML via a separate path and look at it without the browser. Use `curl` or `wget`, or write a little Ruby snippet using OpenURI, then open the resulting HTML in a text editor (*NOT* a word processor) and see what the true HTML path is to the element you want. `tbody` is added because the browser is trying to meet a spec. It was omitted because the author of the HTML didn't care whether it met the spec. We get to work with the "broken" HTML.

Answer (score 3):

This XPATH expression will select all `tbody` tags containing a `<font color="red">`:

```
//tbody[.//font[@color="red"]]
```

Comment: Downvoter, I've added the missing `"` to the XPATH expression.

Comment: what is the function of `.//` here?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: It looks for descendants of the _current element_, in this case the `tbody` tag. If the `.` is left out, the query would look for `font` tags being descendants of the root node.